# Printing a text file using pthread and signals

Tags: c, file, pthreads, signals, posix

I have the following code

```
typedef struct 
{
    char word[64];
} DataStructure;

sigset_t set;
FILE *pFile;

static void *print(void *ptr)
{
    char *message;
    message = (char *)ptr;
    int sig;

    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        sigwait(&set, &sig);
        printf("%s \n", message);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DataStructure Data;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print, (void *)Data.word);

    pFile = fopen("rhyme1.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        fscanf(pFile, "%s", Data.word);
        pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1);  
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*The output should look like:
Hickory,
dickory,
dock,
The
mouse
ran 
up
the
clock.

This code results in:
clock. */
```

I am trying to open a text file and read in each word on the line using scanf. The word is then sent to the 'print' method (via parameter of pthread_create) and prints the word which was read in, when a signal is sent (via pthread_kill). The process repeats until the file has been completely read in and printed.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what Duck suggested.

What you could do is use one thread for reading and one for printing, where each signal eachother in order to stay synced:

```
static void *print(void *ptr)
{
    char *message = (char *)ptr;
    int sig;

    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        sigwait(&set, &sig);
        printf("%s\n", message);
        pthread_kill(thread2, SIGUSR1);  
    }


    return 0;
}
static void *readstr(void *ptr)
{
    char *message = (char *)ptr;
    int sig;

    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        fscanf(pFile, "%s", message);
        pthread_kill(thread1, SIGUSR1);  
        sigwait(&set, &sig);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!! I understand how it all works now! You simplified this in such a helpful format. Can't thank you enough :D

Answer (score 0):

It results in "clock" because you are passing a pointer to Data.word that is going to overridden multiple times before the loop in the thread ever runs.  "Clock" just happens to the last thing that is at that memory location.

```
while(!feof(pFile))
{
    fscanf(pFile, "%s", Data.word);
    pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1);  
}
```

Above is going to flip through the file quickly, possibly before the thread ever executes and certainly before the 2 second sleep ends.

```
while(!feof(pFile))
{
    sigwait(&set, &sig);
    printf("%s \n", message);
    sleep(2);
}
```

You could potentially get a different result on subsequent runs but I doubt you will ever what you expect.  The signal is not going to be queued.